# How can I display full file path of view file in Rails log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

In rails log, we can see these datas.

```
I, [2023-04-03T18:04:57.968359 #77096]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2023-04-03 18:04:57 +0100
D, [2023-04-03T18:04:57.991136 #77096] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Pluck (0.2ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
I, [2023-04-03T18:04:58.011691 #77096]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
D, [2023-04-03T18:04:58.017021 #77096] DEBUG -- :   Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
D, [2023-04-03T18:04:58.017077 #77096] DEBUG -- :   Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
I, [2023-04-03T18:04:58.018070 #77096]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.0ms | Allocations: 922)
I, [2023-04-03T18:04:58.054433 #77096]  INFO -- :   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 37.4ms | Allocations: 60188)
I, [2023-04-03T18:04:58.054628 #77096]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 38.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 65440)
```

I want to see the full path of the view file, when it's rendered.

so, instead of `Rendered home/index.html.erb` , I want it to be `Rendered app/views/home/index.html.erb`

How can I achieve this?

Current my setting for logger in config/envirenments/development.rb is like this.

```
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.log_formatter = Logger::Formatter.new
```

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey patch [the private method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7c70791470fc517deb7c640bead9f1b47efb5539/actionview/lib/action_view/log_subscriber.rb#L65-L69) called `from_rails_root` defined in the `ActionView::LogsSubscriber` class that generates the view file path:

```ruby
require 'action_view'

module ActionView::LogsSubscriber
  private

    def from_rails_root(string) # :doc:
      string = string.sub(rails_root, EMPTY)
      # This line has to be removed in order to keep the 'app/views' string in the path.
      # string.sub!(VIEWS_PATTERN, EMPTY)
      string
    end
end
```

Alternatively, you can override the logger configuration for action view by creating a custom logger class:

```
# config/environments/development.rb

config.action_view.logger = MyCustomViewLogger
```